# extending dijit._WidgetBase from Typescript

Tags: typescript, dojo, widget, extend

I've found many people talking about this issue from 2013-2014, but nothing more recent. I had code working using tsc 2.3.4 (although it produced plenty of compile errors, it produced working JavaScript code), then I updated to 2.6.2 and my code doesn't work any more. I have legacy JavaScript code that extends _WidgetBase and Evented from within JavaScript. I've written a d.ts file to type the class and used /// reference..., import, everything I can think of to make it possible for me to declare a new Typescript class as an extension of the JS class that extends these two dojo classes.
Without giving a whole lot of sample code (because I've rewritten it so many times today I'm not really sure what state it's in), I simply want to know if it's possible to extend a dojo amd loaded class with a class defined in Typescript. If anyone has done it, could you please tell me where I can see an example of it in working code.

Comment: what dojo version are you using now?